# The verb explain a situation which you can not look at the sun?

Tags: sentence-construction

I don't know how to put this question but imagine it is August in summer time and the time shows at noon.Because the sun is shining very strongly or the sun is too bright , even you can not look around or at the sun directly without sunglasses.

My question how can we write this situation.

Here are possible sentences came to mind.

> The sun/sunlight blinded my eyes so I could not look around.
>
> I was blinded by the sun/sunlight.
>
> The sun/sunlight hurted my eyes so I could not look around.
>
> The sun/sunlight dazzled my eyes/me.

By the way the situation I imply is not medical or permanent.

Thank you

Comment: _The sunlight is too bright to look at._ Or: _The sunlight is blinding_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say:

> The sun/sunlight **blinded me** so I could not look around.

*my eyes* is implied so normally I would leave that out and just use "me" to indicate who it was.

> I was blinded by the sun/sunlight.

is OK as is.

Comment: can we use the verb blind for car lights or phone flash lights too?

Comment: Yes you can....

Comment: @Murat If you want to include a sense of being disoriented in addition to not being able to see properly, then dazzled works perfectly here in the same way.  *As I stepped out of the darkened theater I was dazzled by the sun.*  user3169's answer is solid, but I didn't want you to think that dazzle was inappropriate in this situation simply because it was omitted.

Comment: @JasonPatterson Thank you this is what in my mind also .If you dont mind I have a few question more.In movies/cartoon people who was prisoned for a long time, they cannot look at the sun when they went out from prison in a bit joking way. like in your example after staying in a dark for a long time at night( when somebody turns lights on) "can our eyes be dazzled" as well. Can we say "turn the light off please.It dazzle me" ?  and second question if somebody dresses up  ( like a broom or bride), can we say "you look great.you dazzled me" in a bit exaggerating and a complimentary way?

Answer (score 1):

The sunlight was too bright so I couldn't even open my eyes.

Comment: I like that one, but I'd word it like this: _The sunlight was so bright I couldn't even open my eyes._